# How can I change the input element name attribute value in a razor view model using a custom attribute in a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following:

```
@model Pharma.ViewModels.SearchBoxViewModel
<div class="smart-search">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden-xs- col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-right">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

As you can see this is creating an input element.

The view model passed to the view contains the following:

```
public class SearchBoxViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Search")]
    public string SearchPhrase { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment the input element contains a name attribute with the value of "SearchPhrase" but I would like the value to be just "q" without renaming the property.

I would prefer an extension which allows me to call TextBoxFor but without the need of having to supply the Name property, so that the custom attribute somehow sets the value of the Name property automatically to the value specified in the custom attribute.

The following is an example of what I mean:

```
public class SearchBoxViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Search")]
    [Input(Name = "q")]
    public string SearchPhrase { get; set; }
}
```

Combined with:

```
@model Pharma.ViewModels.SearchBoxViewModel
<div class="smart-search">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden-xs- col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-right">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Which would then produce something similar to the following:

```
<div class="smart-search">
    <form action="/Search/Index" method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden-xs- col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-right">
                <label for="Search" class="control-label">Search</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" name="q" id="Search" value="" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I would like this custom attribute to take effect whenever the SearchBoxViewModel is used regardless of what template is used to prevent errors, with the intention of being clear to programmers, while creating a user-friendly query string for the user.

Is it possible to do this using a custom attribute on the SearchPhrase property in a similar fashion to how the display name is changed?

Comment: do you mean that the text in the textbox should default to 'q'?

Comment: Does this not work? `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "form-control" , Name = "q"})`

Comment: @AlwaysAProgrammer no I don't want to set a default value

Comment: @GeorgeLee, in your solution FORM will not post the entered value in the textbox? Bonner, can you explain us what you exactly want?

Comment: @GeorgeLee I would like to change the name however I would like to do this using an attribute in the model so that this applies to all views where TextBoxFor is used.

Comment: You will have to change the name of the Property in the ViewModel itself. You could possibly write a custom HTML helper or a DisplayFor and a template but you cannot do it using TextBoxFor, assuming GeorgeLee's suggestion will not work

Comment: GeorgeLee's suggestion does work, but not now how I want it to, if I have to I will resort to changing the name of the property but I was hoping to avoid this as the name of the Property is for developers and the alias is for end users.

Comment: _"the alias is for end users"_? Unless the user views the page source and inspects the generated html for the input, the user has no idea what your property name is. What is the purpose of trying to do this (and doing it would mean model binding and validation would fail)

Comment: The property name in the view model matches the value of the name attribute in the name element, and the form method is get as this is a simple search form. I also want people to be able to link to searches easily, so rather than having /Search?SearchPhrase=test it is much more friendly to have /Search?q=test

Comment: @br4d I would prefer an extension which allows me to call TextBoxFor but without the need of having to supply the Name property, so that the attribute somehow sets the value of the Name property to the value specified in the attribute. I'm not sure how to put this together so I'm going to start a bounty in the hope that someone can get me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote something simple but can be a start to write the complete solution.

First I wrote a simple `Attribute` with the name you provided:

```
public class InputAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote a Html helper that wraps default `TextBoxFor` and searches for `Input` attribute and if any, It will replace name attribute of generated `HtmlString` from `TextBoxFor`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

    var attr = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (InputAttribute)) as InputAttribute;
    var result = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    if (attr != null)
    {
        var resultStr = result.ToString();
        var match = Regex.Match(resultStr, "name=\\\"\\w+\\\"");
        return new MvcHtmlString(resultStr.Replace(match.Value, "name=\"" + attr.Name + "\""));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then use this html helper in razor views:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Also your model is as follows:

```
public class SearchBoxViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Search")]
    [Input(Name = "q")]
    public string SearchPhrase { get; set; }
}
```

This is a way to complete solution:

1. You have to implement all of the overloads of `TextBoxFor`
2. If you try to send form data to an action with parameter of type `SearchBoxViewModel` you will get a 404 because `ModelBinder` can not bind request parameters to this `ViewModel`. So you will have to write a `ModelBinder` to solve this problem.
3. You have to write `LabelFor` accordingly to match `for` attribute correctly.

**EDIT:** In case of your problem you don't have to deal with case 2 because you send a `GET` request and you will get the form parameters in query string. So you may write your action signature like:

```
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
  // use q to search
}
```

The problem occurs when you have a non-primitive type in your action parameters. In this case `ModelBinder` tries to match query string items (Or request payload) with properties of type of action parameter. For example:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchBoxViewModel vm)
{
  // ...
}
```

In this case, query string (or request payload) has your search query in a parameter named `q` (because name of input is `q` and html form sends request in form of key-values consist of input name and input value). So MVC can not bind `q` to `SearchPhrase` in `LoginViewModel` and you will get a 404.

Comment: I see this as the most promising solution as it matches what I'm looking for, however I'm not sure what you mean on point 2, could you clarify?

Comment: I didn't tested it. when you post the form, form values collected by key value pairs from names of inpu values. so the request body has something different that can't be matched with you entity.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't what you are explicitly asking for but I feel that having a different ViewModel name from the actual form name undermines one of the core conventions in MVC and may be misleading.

As an alternative, you can just add a new property to the VM that mirrors SearchPhrase and has the proper name:

```
public class SearchBoxViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Search")]
    public string SearchPhrase { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Search")]
    public string q
    {
        get { return SearchPhrase; }
        set { SearchPhrase = value; }
    }
}
```

Change your view to use these:

```
@model Pharma.ViewModels.SearchBoxViewModel
<div class="smart-search">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden-xs- col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-right">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.q, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.q, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This would allow you to keep your code in the back end referencing `SearchPhrase` instead of `q` to make it easier on the programmers. Hopefully this view isn't spread out everywhere and you only have a single EditorTemplate or partial.